# Highlighting Graph Points clicked on in HTML Canvas

Tags: html

I currently have an html page that produces a line graph inside a canvas element.  I have also implemented a feature so that when you click on a point in the graph, a table below the canvas displays the information for that graph point, and clears if you click somewhere that isn't a graph point on the canvas.  However, there is currently no indicator for what graph point you have selected.

I would like to make it so that the dot you click on either gets bigger, or highlighted, or something.  Unfortunately, I don't *think* there's any way to do that on the one canvas without needing to redraw the entire graph afterwards.  If I drew a bigger dot on top of the original, I would then need to erase it and replace it with the smaller one, as well as redrawing the segment of the line graph that was covered by the larger dot.

I was looking into using a second canvas on top of the first with identical dimensions, using a z-index to control which was on top.  However, I don't know how this would affect the click event.  If two canvasses are on top of each other, is it possible for the click event to register the lower canvas?  Does it only register the higher one?  I guess I could just change the click event to be for whichever canvas is on top, but keep all the code for drawing on the canvas the same.

Any advice for how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Solved a few of my own questions.

Firstly, the click event will only recognize whichever canvas is on top.  However, I did like I said, and changed my click event to be for the top canvas, while leaving all instructions on the inside to be for the top canvas.  Thank goodness I didn't use the 'this' keyword, or the change would have been much more annoying.

To make the graph points highlight, I first added a second canvas on top of my first one, placing them on top of each other by making their positions "absolute" and giving them a z-index of 0 and 1 respectively.  Then, inside the if statement where the original click event recognized that a point had been clicked on, I told the top canvas to draw a larger dot on the same coordinates as the first dot (which I had saved in an array).  First, I had it clear the top canvas though, so any other highlighted dots would no longer be highlighted.  If the canvas was clicked on somewhere other than a dot, nothing was highlighted.